# Facing CORS issue in Socket.io after deploying my backend app on heroku using express node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, socket.io

I have create small notification app in which I have use socket io to recieve notification from user. In my server file, I have enable cors but still I am getting CORS issue on my client side app. There are some similar question already answered on this platform but it doesn't solve my problem. Below is server file which I deployed on heroku and it's working fine on my local react application. Can you please check what issue have in that file ?

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import morgan from "morgan";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { Server, Socket } from "socket.io";

const app = express();
dotenv.config();

app.use(cors());
const devEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const io = new Server({
  cors: {
    origin: `${
      devEnv ? "http://localhost:3000" : "https://test.netlify.app"
    }`,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
  },
});

let onlineUsers = [];

const addNewUser = (username, socketId) => {
  !onlineUsers.some((user) => user.username === username) &&
    onlineUsers.push({ username, socketId });
};

const removeUser = (socketId) => {
  onlineUsers = onlineUsers.filter((user) => user.socketId !== socketId);
};

const getUser = (username) => {
   
  return onlineUsers.find((user) => user.username === username);
};

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("newUser", (username) => {
   
    addNewUser(username, socket.id);
  });

  socket.on("sendNotification", ({ senderName, receiverName, type }) => {
     const receiver = getUser(receiverName);
    console.log("receiver", receiver);
    io.to(receiver.socketId).emit("getNotification", {
      senderName,
      type,
    });
  });
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    removeUser(socket.id);
  });
});

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true } 
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("this is notification app");
});

 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const server = app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server Running on Port: http://localhost:${PORT}`)
);
io.listen(server);

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(
    () =>
      server
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```

Below error I am getting after doing heroku logs --tail
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O0j2rhO" host=test.herokuapp.com request_id=8902db5a-9f50-49aa-a7b2-756a6528901f fwd="27.6.212.232" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https